# Selecting points within a bounding square

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, gis

Help to make a selection from the database (mysql) of the coordinates.There is a table with fields latitude/longitude.The sample should be in the form of a rectangle. Thank you! [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3J7e.png)

I tried it http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html, but it is necessary in the form of a predetermined size of the rectangle

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. What have you tried? What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  select the point inside a rectangle  is
Assuming that your rect have thr coord ($minLat , $minLng , $maxLat, $maxLng)
 You can simply select the points this way

```
        select * from my_table 
        where 
        point_lat >= $minLat 
        AND point_lat <= $maxLat
        AND point_lng  <= $maxLng
        AND point_lng  >= $minLng;
```

Comment: It is necessary to take into account the latitude (180 -180) and longitude (90 - 90)

Comment: If you use the right ($minLat , $minLng , $maxLat, $maxLng) for you bounds  the select work right ..

Comment: Big Thank! Working!